# How to add value from select option with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have create bellow code and now i want to add value inside select option. Curently i am not getting value in all there drop downbox. For example you can set your option value to help me.

I have created array like this way:

```
var d = new Array("Any","D01 Boat Quay / Raffles Place","D02 Chinatown / Tanjong Pagar","D03 Alexandra / Commonwealth","D04 Harbourfront / Telok Blangah");
var options = '';

for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
   options += '<option>' + d[i] + '</option>';
}
$("#TypeList1").html(options);
sb2.sync();
```

I have tried with this code:

```
var dd = {
            Any : 'Any',
            1 : 'D01 Boat Quay / Raffles Place',
            2 : 'D02 Chinatown / Tanjong Pagar',
            36 : 'D03 Alexandra / Commonwealth',
            37 : 'D04 Harbourfront / Telok Blangah',
            38 : 'D05 Buona Vista / West Coast'
        };

        var select = document.getElementById("TypeList1");
        for(index in dd) {
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(dd[index], index);
        }
```

**MY CODE:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Custom Styled Selectbox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/css/customSelectBox.css" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="customSelectBox.css" />-->
</head>
<body class="noJS">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}
    var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    bodyTag.className = bodyTag.className.replace("noJS", "hasJS");
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.hasJS select.custom1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
}
</style>
<div class="grid-system clearfix">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-9">
            <div class="example clearfix">
                <select class="custom interactive" id="properties">
                    <!--<option value="selectone">Select a Type</option>-->
                    <option value="One" selected>One</option>
                    <option value="Two">Two</option>
                    <option value="Three">Three</option>
                    <option value="Four">Four</option>
                </select>

                <select class="custom interactive" id="TypeList">
                  <option selected>Any</option>
                  <option>Two</option>
                  <option>Three</option>
                  <option>Four</option>
                </select>

                <select class="custom1 interactive1" id="TypeList1">

                </select>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/raw/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script> 
<script src="http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/js/SelectBox.js"></script> 
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script> 
<script src="SelectBox.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
    /*
        This is how initialization normally looks. 
        Typically it's just $("select.custom"), but to make this example more clear 
        I'm breaking from the pattern and excluding interactive
    */
    var sb, sb2;
    $("select.custom").not(".interactive").each(function() {
        sb = new SelectBox({
            selectbox: $(this),
            height: 150,
            width: 200
        });
    });

    $("select.custom1").not(".interactive").each(function() {
        sb2 = new SelectBox({
            selectbox: $(this),
            height: 150,
            width: 250
        });
    });

    /*
        Adding some extra functionality for "interactive" selects
    */
    var TypeList = {
        //selectone: ["Any"],
        'One': ["Any", "Landed", "Condominium", "HDB", "Others"],
        'Two': ["Any", "Landed", "Condominium", "HDB", "Others"],
        'Three': ["Any", "Industrial", "Retail", "Land", "Office", "Others"],
        'Four': ["Any", "Industrial", "Retail", "Land", "Office", "Others"]
        }

    var defaultSelectboxSettings = {
        height: 150,
        width: 150
    };

    var country_SB = null,
    city_SB = null;

    $("select.interactive").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "properties") {
            country_SB = new SelectBox($.extend(defaultSelectboxSettings, {
                selectbox: $(this),
                changeCallback: function(val) {
                    if (TypeList[val]) {
                        city_SB.enable();
                        updateCities(val);
                    }
                    if (val == "selectone") {
                        city_SB.disable();
                    }

                    <!------------------------------Code By Me---------------------------->
                    var getType = jQuery( "#TypeList option:selected" ).text();
                    if(getType == "HDB"){

                        var e = new Array("Any","Boat Quay","Chinatown","Havelock Road","Marina Square");
                        var options = '';

                        for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                           options += '<option>' + e[i] + '</option>';
                        }
                        $("#TypeList1").html(options);
                        sb2.sync();

                    }else{

                        var d = new Array("Any","D01 Boat Quay / Raffles Place","D02 Chinatown / Tanjong Pagar","D03 Alexandra / Commonwealth","D04 Harbourfront / Telok Blangah");
                        var options = '';

                        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                           options += '<option>' + d[i] + '</option>';
                        }
                        $("#TypeList1").html(options);
                        sb2.sync();

                    }
                    <!------------------------------Code By Me---------------------------->

                }
            }));
        } else if ($(this).attr("id") === "TypeList") {
            city_SB = new SelectBox($.extend(defaultSelectboxSettings, {
                selectbox: $(this)
                }));
        }


        //if(jQuery( "#properties option:selected" ).text())
    });

    updateCities($("#properties").val());

    if ($("#properties").val() == "selectone") {
       //city_SB.disable();
    }

    <!------------------------------Code By Me---------------------------->
    if(jQuery( "#TypeList option:selected" ).text()){

        var dd = new Array("Any","D01 Boat Quay / Raffles Place","D02 Chinatown / Tanjong Pagar","D03 Alexandra / Commonwealth","D04 Harbourfront / Telok Blangah");
        var options = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {
           options += '<option>' + dd[i] + '</option>';
        }
        $("#TypeList1").html(options);
        sb2.sync(); 

    }
    <!------------------------------Code By Me---------------------------->

    function updateCities(val) {
        var $select = $("select#TypeList"),
        html = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < TypeList[val].length; i++) {
            html += '<option value="' + TypeList[val][i] + '">' + TypeList[val][i] + '</option>';
        }
        $select.html(html);

        // HACK: chrome is too fast?
        setTimeout(function() {
            city_SB.sync();
        }, 1);
    }

});         
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

your array can look like this

```
var options = [{
    option: option1,
    value: value1
}, {
    option: option2,
    value: value2
}];
```

You will then loop over that json array like so

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i];
}
```

and change this line

```
options += '<option>' + d[i] + '</option>';
```

to (add this into the for loop)

```
options += '<option value="' + d.value + '">' + d.option + '</option>';
```

Comment: but how to define in array?

Comment: like { "text"  : "Option 1", "value" : "Value 1" }

Comment: @Manan let me update my answer,  wasn't sure as to what the actual question was, but yes, your second comment will work

Comment: getting drop-down empty.

Comment: I have added code in my question and working great but when change some option they are repeating again.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

Prepare json object as follows:

```
var data = [
    {
    "id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"},
{
    "id": "id2",
    "name": "name2"}
];
```

Then prepare options list as follows:

```
$.each(data, function(i, option) {
    $('#sel').append($('<option/>').attr("value", option.id).text(option.name));
});
```